# Store data structured without database in javascript

Tags: javascript, data-structures

don't be deterred of the long snippets, for some of you guys, i think, it is quietly easy.

hope the headline says the main message of my question.
What I am trying to do is to structure a amount of `key:value` in combination with objects and arrays pairs.

**Information**

- Its for *easier* templating with [EJS](http://embeddedjs.com/) to have the whole html elements in a config.
- The config contains about 30 *items*
- These are completely logic questions, also for further developing
- I wouldn't use a database for this
- It should be dynamic and extendable

**Example**

```
var items = {
    basic: {
        someKey: [
            {
                id: 'title',
                title: 'Title', 
                type: 'text', ...
            }, ...
        ], ...
    }, ...
}
```

After defining those things (need them later for single operations) i try to get in a structure so i can make it a bit more easier for later use.

```
var sections = [
    {
        title: 'Basic',
        rows: [{
            columns: [
                { title: 'Default', items: items.basic.someKey }, ...
            ]
        }]
    }, ...
]
```

some kind of output would be like this:

```
<input type="<%= item.type %>" id="<%= item.id %>" value="<%= item.value %>" placeholder="<%= item.ph %>">
```

- How would you do those things ?
- Is there a better solution for this ?
- Is the way to store it in javascript better than parse them from xml
  or somewhat ?

Comment: JavaScript objects are pretty much collections of key-value pairs to begin with. I don't see what's tripping you up.

Comment: Its about 3 pages just of javascript objects, that seems to me like a bit inefficient / not the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to check out [JSON](http://www.json.org/). Plenty of libraries for parsing and generating it, and it's based on a subset of JavaScript so you shouldn't have to change your syntax too much if at all.